# Converting String for Delphi to std::string for C++

Tags: c++, delphi, arduino-ide

I am developing a device (ESP32) and there is a rxValue variable that defined as below;

```
std::string rxValue = pCharacteristic->getValue(); <- ESP32 (C++) side
```

But I need to send data (string or character) from Delphi App via SetValueAs... method but when I use

```
Characteristics.SetValueAsString('b'); <- Delphi side (but problematic)
```

**EDIT**: I'm adding SetValueAsString procedure here

```
procedure TBluetoothGattCharacteristic.SetValueAsString(const AValue: string; IsUTF8: Boolean);
begin
  if IsUTF8 then
    Value := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AValue)
  else
    Value := TEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(AValue);
end;
```

Arduino serial monitor shows me a strange character (square) and command cannot be executed.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rxValue.length(); i++) {   <- ESP32 (C++) side
      Serial.print(rxValue[i]);
    }

    if (rxValue.find("a") != -1) { 
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    }
```

As a result, what is the way of sending a string from Delphi to C++ (ESP32 board) as **std::string**. In addition (I didn't want to ask a little question separately.) What is the way of exact comparing rxValue with string? I mean if **rxValue** is exact same as **abcdef** execute a command?
Thanks right now..

Comment: The Arduino language is C++ btw

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? Strings in Delphi 2009+ are 16bit Unicode, but `std::string` is an 8bit string instead. On the Delphi side, how is `SetValueAsString()` declared exactly? If it takes `PChar` generically, change it to take `PAnsiChar` instead.

Comment: @Remy Labeau I am using  Delphi 10.3

Comment: You can't use std::string this way, it's not suitable for interop

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am sorry, I forgot to add SetValueAsString declaration, I've edited (add procedure) question..

Comment: @Alper In Delphi 10.3, `string` is `UnicodeString`. Don't use `TEncoding.Unicode` to encode a `UnicodeString` if the device is expecting an 8bit string, that will give you bytes in UTF-16 instead. When `IsUTF8` is false, use `TEncoding.Default` instead. But either way, you can't assign the result of `TEncoding.GetBytes()` to a `string` like your code snippet is trying to do, you need a separate `TBytes` variable instead, eg: `var Bytes: TBytes; begin Bytes := TEncoding.XXX.GetBytes(AValue); {send Bytes to device} end;`

Comment: @Alper But like David said, `std::string` can't be used for interop across programming language boundaries. It is specific only to C++ (and even to a specific implementation of the C++ standard library). If the device SDK you are trying to use does not expose an API that is compatible with C (vs C++) then you are SOL. You need a different communication channel between your app and the device, such as a Serial/Comm port, Bluetooth, TCP/IP, etc.

Comment: @Alper `SetValue(TBytes)` would seem to be your only option. The Arduino code can easily compare byte values against string characters using something like `memcmp()`, or `strcmp()` with a type-cast from `byte[]` to `char[]`.

Comment: Are you tied to `std::string`? You could instead use `std::u16string` (or `std::wstring`), which are backed by `char16_t` (respectively `wchar_t`)

Comment: @Caleth unfortunately this variable is defined by library so I cannot change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has become more complex after diving into deep. The main problem was 8-Bit / 16-Bit string incompatibility as @RemyLebeau pointed out and @David Heffernan was correct because you cannot use be used std::string for interop across programming languages.

So I've decided to convert my data to 8Bit AnsiString and send but this time I saw that Delphi doesn't support AnsiChar and  Ansistring in mobile compilers anymore (you can read [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/String_Types_(Delphi)#AnsiString) and  [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop)).

So I cannot use 8-Bit strings in Delphi mobile (there are many people they ask "why" to Embarcadero because this means that you cannot use devices that use 8-Bit (many of IoT devices) ) but thank goodness, there are some good people solve this problem with a custom library (you can find the source [here](http://www.kluug.net/orawbytestring.php)).

After adding this library to my app and execute the command like below, problem has been solved;

```
Characteristics.SetValueAsString(RawByteString('b'));
```

**BUT answer is**: You can't use std::string this way, it's not suitable for interop.